# HSSFWorkbook :This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Tags: java, excel, eclipse

I have downloaded Apache Poi Jar but when I write the following code (which a youtube instructor ran with ease), it does not give me any output excel file. What am I doing wrong here? I hover my mouse over `HSSFWorkbook` eclipse tells me

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.
```

The code.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class WriteExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        HSSFWorkbook workbook= new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet= workbook.createSheet("FirstExcelSheet");
        HSSFRow row= sheet.createRow(0);
        HSSFCell cell= row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("1,Cell");
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("excel.xls"));      
        workbook.close();
        workbook.getFirstVisibleTab();
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you write your .xls file?

Comment: check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/FileOutputStream.htm) to give path. that's the problem otherwise it is working. already tried.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing use XSSFWorkbook instead of HSSFWorkbook  take a look at this [link](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/),
and the second thing you have to out stream this file add this line

```
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("slsx.xlsx")) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
```

so your code should be like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");

    XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("test");
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Writesheet.xlsx"))) {
        workbook.write(out);
    }
    System.out.println("Writesheet.xlsx written successfully");
}
```

Comment: I modified my code and made it exactly like yours(with my own folder path of course) but still nothing happens.

Comment: have you added XSSF?

Comment: yes, but your first line of code says XSSFF so i removed the extra F

Comment: it is not about the XSSF. it is working with HSSF. The problem is about given path.

Comment: Yep it should be , wait a second

Comment: i have updated my answer even the last one was working perfect, anyway once you open the project you will find the excel sheet which we created therer

Answer (score 0):

you should add your path in this line like:

```
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("{yourpath}/excel.xls"));
```

it works..